# Como adicionar "" em um input

Tags: c

Como faço para adicionar "" em um input? Eu tentei fazer de varias maneiras mas a que eu cheguei mais perto foi essa, porem não retorna uma palavra, retorna "(null)"

```
int main(void) {
        char p;
        char x = 34;

        printf("Palavra: ");
        scanf("%s\n", p);
        printf("%c%s%c\n", x, p, x);

        return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa linha:

```
scanf("%s\n", p);
```

deveria ser:

```
scanf("%s\n", &p);
```

Mas se quer que caiba uma palavra não vai caber, só cabe um caracter. Para caber uma palavra use array.